# How can I use an {{expression}} in (or as) the name of a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two class-restricted directives, named `fooThing` and `barThing`.

I have a variable, `baz`, in my template scope that is set to either `foo` or `bar`.

How can I use that scope variable in the *name* of the directive for an element?

When I do `<div class="{{baz}}-thing"></div>`, `{{baz}}` is replaced properly, but the directive is not loaded.

When I do `<div class="foo-thing"></div>`, the directive is loaded properly.

I have a hunch that this has something to do with Angular's digest/compile cycle, but I'm afraid I don't know how to work around it.

How can I get Angular to compile that part of the template *first* so that my expression is evaluated, and then have it compile *again* so it recognizes it as a directive?

Comment: Not sure but it may have something to do with `priority` property of the directive definition.

Comment: Thanks tosh, it looks like `priority` only applies to the order in which directives are compiled. My problem is that my directive is never recognized in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a directive that creates directives (a kind of directive factory), as suggested by Anders, is what I'm after. [Guillaume86](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172074/guillaume86) provided [a good method](http://bit.ly/Y0pomA) for doing that.

Comment: I'm still a little confused about what you're "allowed" to do in a compile function vs a linking function. According to the docs...

If you are transforming the template DOM, you are *"required"* to use the compile function.

The **linking** function is executed **after** the template has been cloned into an instance. So any DOM changes made here will only apply to that instance.

So I get that compile functions act on the template, and linking functions act on the instances, but I don't understand why/when you should transform the DOM in one or the other.

Comment: It isn't apparant until you use something like ng-repeat. In most cases you won't need the compile function, you just set the directive template and Angular does it for you. But in some cases you need more compile logic than what feels natural in a template and that's when you'd use the compile function. The linking function can contain DOM transformations, but they will get executed for every instance which could affect performance. The only DOM transformations you should be doing in your linking function are those where you need your scope, since that isn't available in the compile function.

Answer (score 0):

For that to work your template would have to first be compiled and executed on a scope (to replace {{baz}}), and then compiled and executed again to get the "foo-thing" directive going. It's possible, but it would probably cause other issues.

What you could do is create sort of a directive factory, a directive that creates another directive. Here's an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
    myApp.directive('factory', function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                type: '=factory'
            },
            replace: true,
            link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
                var compiled = $compile('<'+ $scope.type +'></'+ $scope.type +'>')($scope);
                elem.append(compiled);
            }
        };
    });
    myApp.directive('concrete', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: "<div>I'm concrete!</div>",
            link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {

            }
        };
    });

    function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.directiveType = "concrete";
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div factory="directiveType"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That kind of stuff should go in the compile function of the directive, I use the ngInclude source code as an example when I need this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js

Comment: You would you do that in the compile function? You don't have access to the scope in the compile function, and you need the scope to get access to the "directiveType" property.

Comment: You can return a linking function from the compile function like in the ngInclude directive. I'm really just doing that to follow angular source code conventions, it's also working the way you did ;)

Comment: Well, if you put the code in the linking function that your compile function returns then that's exactly the same as my example. I would even argue that it's confusing to use the compile for a directive if you're not going to transform the element inside the compile function.

Comment: I guess it's done this way in AngularJS source code because because linking is not supposed to do the template DOM transformations (that's the compile step job), but in this case you don't really have the choice so you clearly express that your directive does template DOM transformations by using the compile method.

Comment: But you're not using the compile function? You're just returning a linking function, which is the same as omitting the compile function and just having a linking function. You can't really compare it with ng-include since it uses the attributes from the compiled element, but that's not needed in this case.

Comment: It's not my code it's the angularJS source code. Yours is not watching for changes: http://jsfiddle.net/g/Y4f95/2/, and when you will watch for changes, you will need to clean the DOM and destroy scope, so it's a lot easier to copy the ngInclude and change it a little like that: http://jsfiddle.net/g/Y4f95/3/

Comment: Even if it was a requirement to be able to change 'directiveType' and make the directive reload with a new directive, there still wouldn't be a need for the compile function.

Comment: Like I said before, it's not a functionnal need, it's about coding style/conventions, no need for a debate here.